# For filenames, are underscores or dashes more common in Unix file names?

Tags: files, filenames

When you are naming files with multiple words in the name, is it more common in Unix systems to use underscores, camel case, or dashes to separate the words?

Comment: When **I'm** naming them? Space.

Comment: Traditional Unix commands and files don't tend to have more than one word at all.  Most are a few letters.  For your own files it is really up to you.  I avoid spaces because they are a pain to deal with on the command line.  The [POSIX portable file name character set](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_276) is quite restricted: alphanumeric, dot, underscore, and dash.

Comment: As opposed to which naming method?

Comment: [This question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44153/good-style-practices-for-separators-in-file-or-directory-names) may be interesting.

Answer (score 51):

On one of my random systems:

```
$ find /usr/bin -xdev -type f -name '*-*' | wc -l                # hyphen
1019
$ find /usr/bin -xdev -type f -name '*_*' | wc -l                # underscore
311
$ find /usr/bin -xdev -type f -name '*[a-z][A-Z][a-z]*' | wc -l  # camelcase
2
$ find /usr/bin -xdev -type f -name '* *' | wc -l                # space
0
```

Your mileage may vary.  There's a lot of personal preference involved -- my home directory is probably very much skewed towards hyphens, because underscore and camelcase involves shifting, and space has difficulties with quoting.